# Calculating Timestamp within Docker Container (running in ECS) and passing to AWS CLI DynamoDB Put-Item

Tags: docker, ubuntu, time, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am in the midst of a side project that requires me to pass a timestamp of when a build finishes (thereabouts) inside a Docker container running on AWS ECS Fargate into a DynamoDB table. As far as use case, it serves as a sort of custom audit log for this specific system.

I am trying to find a good way to pass a timestamp as an ENV VAR and into the `aws dynamodb put-item` CLI operation. My CLI Query looks like this:
`aws dynamodb put-item --table-name build-audit --item '{ "date": {"S": '\"$(DTG)\"'} }'`

Previously, I had tried `ENV DTG=$(date +%s)` but get this error `Syntax error - can't find = in "+%s)". Must be of the form: name=valuedockerfile-utils(33)`.

I tried running it straight up as `ENV DTG=date` and a few variations of such (`date`, $(date), date with backticks, etc) and they would end up getting passed as the literal string versus the actual timestamp into my Table.

I then switched off to doing something like this

```
...docker stuff...
date > dtg.txt && \
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name build-audit --item '{ "date": {"S": '\"$(cat ./dtg.txt)\"'} }'
```

And I would get an argument error with the CLI (though running `cat` on the file would do what I wanted it to do), but I have no idea how to pass that output in the CLI.

Is there any other method from within Docker I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this example will help you get to what you need:

```
FROM busybox
ARG START
ENV STARTX=${START}
RUN echo ${START}
RUN echo ${STARTX}
```

Then:

```sh
docker build \
--tag=example \
--build-arg=START=$(date +'%y%m%d') \
.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM busybox
Step 2/5 : ARG START
Step 3/5 : ENV STARTX=${START}
Step 4/5 : RUN echo ${START}
190701
Step 5/5 : RUN echo ${STARTX}
190701
Successfully built a0f3f19bd9ad
Successfully tagged deleteme:latest
```

Provided by way of the `--build-arg` and accessible within the build process `RUN echo ${START}`

Because and environment variable is assigned during the build (`ENV STARTX=${START}`), `${STARTX}` will be available within the container too:

```sh
docker inspect example --format="{{.Config.Env}}"
[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin STARTX=190701]
```

**NB** `ARG START` and `ENV STARTX...` purely for clarity but could the same name.

Comment: This did work, and was a pretty elegant solution as well, but from what I could tell it was only passing the Data Time Group from when I built the image, I would be reusing the container over and over with ECS and it would pass the same date (therefore, not at all) into DynamoDB. That said, I am dealing with an issue of passing `cat` or `echo $(var)` through the CLI into DynamoDB and have decided for another way of going about it. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood. You want "build in" a container not "build of" the container.